# How to set application credential details in CI?

Tags: continuous-integration, buildkite

How to set application credential details in buildkite so that it can be used as part of tests?

Any help?

thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to store them in an [agent environment hook](https://buildkite.com/docs/agent/v3/hooks), which is a script file you need to put on the host running the agent, and is invoked just before every job the agent runs:

```sh
# /etc/buildkite-agent/hooks/environment

set -eu
echo "--- :house_with_garden: Setting up the environment"

export APPLICATION_PASSWORD="xxx"
```

and then use them in your pipeline commands from the environment:

```yaml
# .buildkite/pipeline.yml

steps:
- label: Run tests
  command: ./run-tests --password="$$APPLICATION_PASSWORD"
```

The double-dollar escapes the variable for pipeline upload, making sure that the password is not interpolated into the YAML and then submitted to buildkite.com. It will then be interpolated once the agent runs the command.

You could also access `$APPLICATION_PASSWORD` within your script to avoid mentioning it in the yaml at all.

The agent environment hook works best if you're running long lived agents, or use something like the elastic-ci-stack-for-aws which has a shared environment hook for this sort of thing:

https://github.com/buildkite/elastic-ci-stack-for-aws#build-secrets

but there are a few other options, too:

https://buildkite.com/docs/pipelines/secrets

Comment: Thank you. Should I add the agent hook as part of pipeline.yml file? (sorry I'm very new to these stuff). What I exactly need is to store the login password of my application so that my automation tests can use the credentials to login

Comment: No worries! Agent hooks should be stored on the host running your agent. On Linux, for instance, you'd usually put it in `/etc/buildkite-agent/hooks/environment`. I'll modify the example above to demonstrate using a password in a pipeline yml.

Comment: Great thank you so much... Can I add three different passwords (for different roles) and access it like this? In that case, there will be difference in pipeline.yml file right?

Comment: You can add and use as many environment variables as you like :-)